# Sort a list of dictionaries by keys in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of dictionary like this `[{1: {'Name': 't1', 'seq': 1}}, {3: {'Name': 't3', 'seq': 3}}, {2: {'Name': 't2', 'seq': 2}}]`

And I want to sort this list based on just the key (and not the value of that key)

Expected output is
`[{1: {'Name': 't1', 'seq': 1}}, {2: {'Name': 't3', 'seq': 2}}, {3: {'Name': 't2', 'seq': 3}}]`

I know this can be done by getting key as list then sort them and then create another list, but i am looking for more elegant may be a one liner solution

Comment: You aren't just sorting the dicts, but you are altering their content with some unspecified logics.

Comment: Why are you making dictionaries that all have only one entry? How do you want to sort the list when one of the dictionaries has several entries?

Comment: If there really is always only one entry in each dictionary, then does `sorted(dlist, key=lambda d: list(d.keys())[0])` work?`

Comment: @ThePhoton yes the entry will be one, the target is to sort the dict just based on the key itself and not the value of the key. Yes , your solution seem to work, could you please leave a reply, i will marl that as an answer, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the key arg at sorted that gets a function to sort
docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

```
sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0])
```